# mod_pagespeed refuses to flush cache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, dreamhost, page-speed

I have mod_pagespeed running on my Dreamhost Ubuntu 12.04 VPS. Every time I turn on  mod_pagespeed *again* the old header display (top black bar with data I removed - is shown on all pages. This despite the fact that the new version has been on for a few days and me running the command

```
sudo touch  /var/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush
```

The command and path to it was suggested by Dreamhost [here](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Page_Speed_Optimization) and is the same as suggested at [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system) itself. When I turn off mod_pagespeed and restart the VPS the latest version returns. But I really would like to use mod_pagespeed.

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this and get mod_pagespeed to load the proper content?

Comment: I too have noticed this issue. Have you tried clearing /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/ as that's the default cache directory AFAIK.

Comment: I have `/var/mod_pagespeed/cache# ls
!clean!time!  http,3A  prop_page  rname`. Under /var/cache I have `/var/cache# ls
analog  apt  debconf  dictionaries-common  fontconfig  git  ldconfig  man  pbuilder` . Do you mean you empty the cache folder completely by deleting all folders like `http,3A` `prop_page` and `rname`?

Comment: Might just do that. Reading http://craterdesigns.com/how-to-easily-clear-mod_pagespeed-cache on a similar approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](http://craterdesigns.com/how-to-easily-clear-mod_pagespeed-cache) and suggested by @i-CONICA I did a removal of the cache folder and re-created it:

```
sudo mv /var/mod_pagespeed/cache /var/mod_pagespeed/cache.del
sudo rm -rf /var/mod_pagespeed/cache.del
sudo mkdir /var/mod_pagespeed/cache
sudo chown dhapache:dhapache /var/mod_pagespeed/cache
```

**NB** Group and user `dhapache` are Dreamhost specific

Then I restarted the VPS server doing a reboot. After that the new content was served. All good. Dreamhost got back to me, but that not add any new intel. If they do at a later stage I will update the answer with another and or better solution.